# Using Range in addAttributeToFilter for a drop down attribute does not work as expected

Tags: magento2

I am trying to filter my product collection using Range for a drop down attribute.

Attribute name - btu_input_exact

Here is my code to fetch product collection

```
$productCollection = $collectionFactory->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('btu_input_exact')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', ['in' => $brands])
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
```

And now this is the code to add range filter

```
$attributeCode = 'btu_input_exact';

// Set the values for filtering
$minValue = '110,000'; // Example minimum value
$maxValue = '130,000'; // Example maximum value

// Add filters to the product collection
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
    $attributeCode,
    ['gteq' => $minValue]
);

$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
    $attributeCode,
    ['lteq' => $maxValue]
);
```

This is the query that I get when I use echo $productCollection->getSelect();

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_manufacturer`.`value` AS `manufacturer`, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`, `at_btu_input_exact`.`value` AS `btu_input_exact` 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_manufacturer` ON (`at_manufacturer`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_manufacturer`.`attribute_id` = '83') AND (`at_manufacturer`.`store_id` = 0) 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_btu_input_exact` ON (`at_btu_input_exact`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_btu_input_exact`.`attribute_id` = '208') AND (`at_btu_input_exact`.`store_id` = 0) 
WHERE (at_manufacturer.value IN('21321', '21289')) AND (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = '1') AND (at_btu_input_exact.value >= '110,000') AND (at_btu_input_exact.value <= '130,000')
```

This query has the condition at the end but it is not fetching the data. I have made sure that I have a product withing this range.

[image]

I feel this is happening as this attribute is drop down attribute and the values are saved as option_ids. here is the option_id values for the above values.

[image]

[image]

So I tried using option_ids in my code. Example code using option_ids

```
$attributeCode = 'btu_input_exact';

// Set the values for filtering
$minValue = '6487'; // Example minimum value
$maxValue = '6428'; // Example maximum value

// Add filters to the product collection
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
    $attributeCode,
    ['gteq' => $minValue]
);

$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
    $attributeCode,
    ['lteq' => $maxValue]
);
                                    
echo $productCollection->getSelect();die;
```

This is the query that I get

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_manufacturer`.`value` AS `manufacturer`, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`, `at_btu_input_exact`.`value` AS `btu_input_exact`
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_manufacturer` ON (`at_manufacturer`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_manufacturer`.`attribute_id` = '83') AND (`at_manufacturer`.`store_id` = 0) 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_btu_input_exact` ON (`at_btu_input_exact`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_btu_input_exact`.`attribute_id` = '208') AND (`at_btu_input_exact`.`store_id` = 0) 
WHERE (at_manufacturer.value IN('21321', '21289')) AND (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = '1') AND (at_btu_input_exact.value >= '6487') AND (at_btu_input_exact.value <= '6428')
```

But still the productCollection is empty. I know this could be happening because of comma in my values and also it is a drop down attribute. But I need a way to filter productCollection for this.

I can try to fetch the complete productCollection and remove the products according to my condition manually. But I have a lot of products on my website and this will make the process too slow.

Could someone suggest a way to filter productCollection according to above condition.

Comment: Can you remove the quote? I think it's related to data type. So that use `110000` and `130000` directly (without quote and comma) and retry.